# Compiling fluoride bluetooth stack for embedded linux

Tags: bluetooth, embedded-linux, android-bluetooth, ninja, gn

Has anyone been able to compile fluoride bluetooth stack separately for an embedded linux device?

 There is a guide at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/181144a50114c824cfe3cdfd695c11a074673a5e/README.md, but following these instructions `gn gen` fails without getting the common-mk folder and modding some build files so there are no missing variables, folders etc. 
 
I have been able to generate Ninja files, but when building, there are missing gtest and modp_b64 headers. After getting them from Google's source search, Ninja seems to be able to run a bit without errors, but ultimately fails with:

```
In file included from ../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop.h:18:
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop_current.h:209:3: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same<MessagePumpForUI, MessagePumpLibevent>::value' "MessageLoopCurrentForUI::WatchFileDescriptor is not supported when MessagePumpForUI is not a MessagePumpLibevent."
  static_assert(std::is_same<MessagePumpForUI, MessagePumpLibevent>::value,
  ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop_current.h:214:28: error: no type named 'Mode' in 'base::MessagePumpGlib'; did you mean 'MessagePumpLibevent::Mode'?
                           MessagePumpForUI::Mode mode,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           MessagePumpLibevent::Mode
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/watchable_io_message_pump_posix.h:55:8: note: 'MessagePumpLibevent::Mode' declared here
  enum Mode {
       ^
In file included from ../../third_party/libchrome/base/run_loop.cc:10:
In file included from ../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop.h:18:
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop_current.h:215:28: error: no type named 'FdWatchController' in 'base::MessagePumpGlib'; did you mean 'MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatchController'?
                           MessagePumpForUI::FdWatchController* controller,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatchController
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_pump_libevent.h:28:9: note: 'MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatchController' declared here
  class FdWatchController : public FdWatchControllerInterface {
        ^
In file included from ../../third_party/libchrome/base/run_loop.cc:10:
In file included from ../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop.h:18:
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/message_loop_current.h:216:28: error: no type named 'FdWatcher' in 'base::MessagePumpGlib'; did you mean 'MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatcher'?
                           MessagePumpForUI::FdWatcher* delegate);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatcher
../../third_party/libchrome/base/message_loop/watchable_io_message_pump_posix.h:17:9: note: 'MessagePumpLibevent::FdWatcher' declared here
  class FdWatcher {
        ^
4 errors generated.
```

All the errors and missing files are coming from `third_party/libchrome`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed instructions at https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/bt/README.md

In addition to instructions there, I had to resolve issues in the build script manually. I was able to compile the bluetooth stack successfully in Ubuntu 21.04

- Replace `//bt` with `/home/udara/fluoride/bt` in build files.

Used `sed` command. Change to your fluoride directory as appropriate.

```
for file in $(grep -r -l "//bt"); do sed -i 's/\/\/bt/\/home\/udara\/fluoride\/bt/g' $file; done
```

- Copied `common-mk` symlink generated by `bootstrap.py` to the fluoride directory.
- And replaced `//common-mk` with `/home/udara/fluoride/common-mk`.

```
for file in $(grep -r -l "//common-mk"); do sed -i 's/\/\/common-mk/\/home\/udara\/fluoride\/common-mk/g' $file; done
```

- Installed few missing dependencies

```
sudo apt install llvm
sudo apt install libc++abi-dev
```

- Copied `/home/udara/fluoride/bt/output/out/Default/gen/ABS_PATH/home/udara/fluoride/bt/gd/dumpsys/bundler/bundler_generated.h` to `/home/udara/fluoride/bt/gd/dumpsys/`

```
cp /home/udara/fluoride/bt/output/out/Default/gen/ABS_PATH/home/udara/fluoride/bt/gd/dumpsys/bundler/bundler_generated.h /home/udara/fluoride/bt/gd/dumpsys/
```

- Created directory named `output` in the `bt` directory.
- Set environment variables

```
# this is set by bootstrap.py
export STAGING_DIR=/home/udara/fluoride/staging

# you have to manually set this
export OUTPUT_DIR=/home/udara/fluoride/bt/output
```

- Then compile the bluetooth stack with

```
./build.py --output ${OUTPUT_DIR} --platform-dir ${STAGING_DIR} --clang
```

- Add the following lines to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`

```
<policy>
    ...
    <allow own="org.chromium.bluetooth"/>
    <allow own="org.chromium.bluetooth.Manager"/>
</policy>
```

- Finally run fluoride with

```
cd /home/udara/fluoride/bt/output/debug
sudo ./btadapterd --hci=0 INIT_gd_hci=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the common-mk issues are coming up because between the instructions being written, and now, libchrome has added a `BUILD.gn` file - so it is being used, instead of the substitute one in `build/secondary/third-party/libchrome` as intended. To fix this part of the build, just delete `third-party/libchrome/BUILD.gn` - should prevent the need for a lot of build fiddling.

The second part is because of the configuration of libchrome. Once you remove the file mentioned, then you need to modify `build/secondary/third-party/libchrome/BUILD.gn` to add the following not just to the source_set (as is done in upstream) but also to `libchrome_config` for downstream users:

```
 defines = [
    "__ANDROID_HOST__=1",
 ]
```

This will affect the build config so it doesn't try to use glib.

My best work on getting this to build is here, though I haven't gotten it to work entirely. https://github.com/rpavlik/fluoride I did this mostly as an experiment, feel free to continue where I left off.